# Is the song "Paradise City" written about a specific city?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, guns-n-roses

In the song *Paradise City* by  *Guns N' Roses*, is the "Paradise City" referenced by the song and its title based on an actual city similar to how "The Jungle" in *Welcome to the Jungle* refers to L.A.?

Answer (score 10):

Wikipedia is [rather vague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise_City#Song):

> Guns N' Roses' lead guitarist, Slash, states that the song was written
>   in the back of a rental van as they were on their way back from
>   playing a gig in San Francisco with the band Rock N Riders. He says
>   that the band was in the back of the van, drinking and playing
>   acoustic guitars, when he came up with the intro. Duff McKagan and
>   Izzy Stradlin started playing along. Slash started humming a melody
>   when Axl Rose sang, "Take me down to the Paradise City." Slash chimed
>   in with "Where the grass is green and the girls are pretty." Axl sang
>   the first line again, where Slash shouted out "Where the girls are fat
>   and they've got big titties." Axl finished with "Take ... me ...
>   home!" Slash preferred his second line but the rest of the band felt
>   differently. He was outvoted and they used the first line. The band
>   then expanded upon the rest of the lyrics in rounds.
>
> During a 1988 interview, Rose told "Hit Parader" magazine that "the
>   verses are more about being in the jungle; the chorus is like being
>   back in the Midwest or somewhere."

Songfacts however offers [a reasonable theory](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=5635):

> Much like "Welcome To The Jungle," this was inspired by Los Angeles,
>   where the band was living. The verses deal with the rough life on the
>   streets, but the chorus was based on Axl Rose's memories of the
>   Midwest, with images of green grass, innocence and possibility.

A contributor added more details:

> On 93.1 WIBC FM, a radio station in Indianapolis, Indiana, Jake Query,
>   who is a friend of Axl Rose, explained that the part of the song where
>   they sing, "Where the grass is green, and the girls are pretty" is
>   about when Axl Rose and his family would go down to Bloomington,
>   Indiana.

However, note that Slash claims in his autobiography that he came up with that line (which is the source for the Wikipedia entry quoted above).

Answer (score 2):

Paradise City is not a real city but pleas to be taken to heaven. At least that is what William said when we met just prior to Guns N Roses being officially formed. Met him at a state fair in LA in 1985.